# modifing a xml file using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax

Can we modify or update xml file using SAX parser. If yes, please provide me the sample code or any helpful link

my xml file looks like this

```
<vertices>
<vertex>
<name>user1</name>
<type>Ashok</type>
<nickname>nickuser1</nickname>
</vertex>
</vertices>"
```

I want to change "user1" to say "user2". Help me out

Comment: You have many options , modifying the XML its best suited for a dom parser. Sax is intended for quick read access with minimal memory overhead , not for writing documents.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459712/modify-xml-file-with-xpath

Comment: This question helped me with the same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687799/parsing-and-modifying-xml-string-with-sax-parser

Comment: @ Kenneth Clark if I use DOM entire xml file will be loaded that should not happen in my case. And does this xpath load the entire xml file?

Comment: @ a.hrdie: this link produces the updated result but I want to put the updated result into the same xml file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are reluctant to use a DOM parser because you have a large XML you can use the XPATH or XLST to transform the xml.

[What is best way to change one value in XML files in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672770/what-is-best-way-to-change-one-value-in-xml-files-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to do it in [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)... It is a lot more efficient/simpler than DOM or SAX based solutions... for further reading here is an article entitled [manipulate XML the Ximple Way](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/36379)...

```
import java.io.*;
public class modifyXML {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/vertices/vertex/name/text()");
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        // using XPath
        int i=ap.evalXPath();
        if(i!=-1){
            xm.updateToken(i, "user2");
        }
        xm.output("output.xml");
    }
}
```